# Wrong voltage sent to output

Tags: voltage, voltage-measurement, board, ul

Using miniLab1008, I am trying to send 10V to my D/A OUT0 but it sends only 5V and when I send 5V, I get 2.5V. I am using the universal library example VOut01.c
Is this a board problem? However using the software that came with the board everything seems normal.

Comment: Do you have some links to the above board/code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [user manual](http://www.mccdaq.com/PDFs/Manuals/minilab-1008.pdf) says on page 28:

> Maximum output range: 0-5 volts

It's USB powered, and simply doesn't have 10 V available. So the reference voltage is 5 V, for a digital value of 1023. A 512 value will give you 2.5 V.

\$ V_{out} = \dfrac{data}{1024} \cdot  5 V \$

The inputs can process 10 V input voltage, though.